# Group By with min distance in mysql

Tags: mysql, google-maps-api-3, distance

I am stuck with this mysql query

```
SELECT hotels.radius,
hotels.hotel_id,
hotel_names.name_id,
hotel_names.image,
hotel_names.name,
hotel_names.description, 
hotels.hotel_address,hotels.lat,hotels.lng, 
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians( 45.4046728 ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * 
cos( radians( lng ) - radians( 11.8485039 ) ) + 
sin( radians( 45.4046728 ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM hotels 
INNER JOIN hotel_names 
ON hotels.name_id = hotel_names.name_id 
ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

The result of this query 
[image: results page]

The expected result should be the minimum distance with
GROUP BY of **name_id** and it is marked as yellow

[image: expected result]

check this http://gyazo.com/18b705b042e289d5d0a2dc9adde4c715 and expected result should be hotel ids 17,23, 26,28,25
Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and post the answer and expected answer as text instead of picture.

Comment: @Rahul check this http://gyazo.com/18b705b042e289d5d0a2dc9adde4c715 and expected result should be hotel ids 17,23, 26,28,25

Comment: @SamArulRaj Um, that's still a picture. Provide proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle

Comment: @Strawberry i asked guys  to find the answer ! here the discussion is not about picture or text

Comment: This is a great question!  Here is a blog which dicusses strategies for possible solutions: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 1):

Here is your query, which is admittedly verbose:

```
SELECT y.radius,y.hotel_id,y.name_id,y.image,y.name,y.description, y.hotel_address,y.lat,hotels.lng,y.distance
FROM (
    SELECT hotels.name_id, min( 6371 * acos( cos( radians( 45.4046728 ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians( 11.8485039 ) ) + sin( radians( 45.4046728 ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS mindistance FROM hotels INNER JOIN hotel_names ON hotels.name_id = hotel_names.name_id GROUP BY hotels.name_id
) AS x
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT hotels.radius,hotels.hotel_id,hotel_names.name_id,hotel_names.image,hotel_names.name,hotel_names.description, hotels.hotel_address,hotels.lat,hotels.lng, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians( 45.4046728 ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians( 11.8485039 ) ) + sin( radians( 45.4046728 ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
    FROM hotels INNER JOIN hotel_names
    ON hotels.name_id = hotel_names.name_id
) AS y
ON y.name_id = x.name_id AND y.distance = x.mindistance;
```

I used the `self-join` strategy, which first obtains a table containing nothing other than hotel `name_id` group and a variable I have named `mindistance`, which is the minimum distance from your hard-coded location, for each group.  This intermediate table is called `x` in the above query, and would look something like this if you were to run it as a separate query:

```
--------------------------------
| name_id |    mindistance     |
--------------------------------
|    1    | 4.932831427954488  |
|    2    | 2.7469817798115566 |
|    4    | 6.677055216749393  |
|    5    | 4.359018738728522  |
|    6    | 4.6047991286091055 |
--------------------------------
```

Then I join this table back to the table which results from your original `INNER JOIN` query in your above question.  Notice that the `ON` condition of this `INNER JOIN` matches only one record per `name_id` which also has the minimum distance in that group.  I didn't sort my result, but I welcome you to try this query and let us know if it works for you.

Upon further reflection, this query could have been simplified by a few things.  If you had a single table for your initial result that would have helped.  Also, if you had created a dedicated column which contained the distance that also would have made things easier to read.